# Excel file can not be saved in PHP COM Application

Tags: php, excel, com, ole

we are having issues saving excel sheets in PHP.

Minimalistic code:

```
// R: is a Ramdisk
$filename = 'R:\\sheets\\ExcelFile_123.xlsx';
$application = new COM("Excel.Application", null, CP_UTF8);
$workbook = $application->Workbooks->Open($filename);
$workbook->save();
```

The call to save will throw a com_exception with message "Source: Microsoft Excel Description: Das Dokument wurde nicht gespeichert."
(German for "The document was not saved.")

When any worksheet of the workbook has been opened and i am trying to save the worksheet again i get another com_exception with message "Source: Microsoft Excel Description: Zugriff auf 'ExcelFile_123.xlsx' verweigert."
(German for "Access to 'ExcelFile_123.xlsx' denied.")

I checked following things:

- The Excel file does not have any Links to other sheets.
- The Excel file is not write protected.
- The file can be written to disk by PHP (PHP has write access to the file and folder)
- The Excel file is not shared.
- No other Excel Application is open.

I toggled every setting of the ones mentioned above and even tried https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2589410/access-denied-error-message-when-you-save-a-workbook-to-a-unc-share-in

Solutions that are **not suitable**:

- Using another PHP Excel Library (The Excel files heavily depend on calculations and conditions)
- Using Microsoft Grap
- Using Microsoft Office 365
- Using Google SPreadsheet

Question:
Why can't i save the excel file, even though i have write access?

---

System information

- Server: Windows 2012 R2
- Webserver: Apache 2.4
- PHP: 5.5.14 (I am aware of the security implications)

PHP com_dotnet extension:

```
com_dotnet\
COM support enabled\
DCOM support    disabled\
.Net support    enabled\
Directive   Local Value Master Value\
com.allow_dcom  0   0\
com.autoregister_casesensitive  1   1\
com.autoregister_typelib    0   0\
com.autoregister_verbose    0   0\
com.code_page   no value    no value\
com.typelib_file    no value    no value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be an issue with user profile under which your PHP application is running. Please check article on server-side office automation of office products (it has common problems listed). To see if the problem is actually the account, I would try to change the account under Apache (PHP) is running to your account (or simply start Apache command line to see if it fixes the problem).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office

https://theether.net/download/Microsoft/kb/288367.html

BTW, there are (paid) alternatives as well that can do calculations and run server-side.

Comment: So it seems that even though PHP can read and write the document, the Excel Application opened and controlled by PHP can not.